# Prove that the function $f(x) = 3x + 7$ is continuous at every point $x_0\in\Bbb R$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, continuity

I'm trying to understand this problem using epsilon and delta definition. I looked at the solution and see that you fix $x_0$, let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\delta = \min(\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, 1)$  I am not sure where this value come from for delta. How do you know what to set delta to?

Comment: This delta does not work for this problem.

Comment: No, if $|x-x_0|>\frac{\epsilon}{3}$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|=3|x-x_0|>\epsilon$. So take $x=x_0+\frac{5}{12}\epsilon$ and your $\delta$ fails.

Comment: oops i wrote it wrong, it is min($\varepsilon$/5, 1)

Comment: but my question is how do you know what to set delta to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A point to get used to is that typically you do not fix the delta in advance. You start the calculation and then the delta comes out. If you rewrite the proof, you might streamline the presentation.

Let us go through it:

Let $x_0$ be fixed. 
Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to show there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for $|x-x_0| < \delta$  we have $|f(x)- f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

Now, $|f(x)- f(x_0)| = |(3x+7) - (3x_0 +7)| = |3x - 3x_0|= 3 |x-x_0|$. 
We want this to be less than $\epsilon$ and we can chose a condition on $|x-x_0|$. One possible choice is $\delta = \epsilon/3$, since then $3|x-x_0|< 3 \delta = \epsilon$.

But you can also chose $\delta = \epsilon/35.7$ or $\delta = \min (29, \epsilon/7)$ or whatever still works.

Once you have found this you can rewrite the argument more concisely:

> Let $x_0$ be fixed. Let $\epsilon > 0$ and let $\delta= \epsilon/3$. For $|x-x_0| < \delta$  we have $|f(x)- f(x_0)| = |(3x+7) - (3x_0 +7)| = |3x - 3x_0|= 3 |x-x_0| < 3 \delta = \epsilon $.

Comment: Sorry for the auto-rejected edit. It was an accident as I did another edit in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that for any "really small" $\epsilon > 0$ then there is a $\delta$ (the value of which is determined by $\epsilon$; thus I find it useful for my comprehension to write $\delta_{\epsilon}$; such notation isn't required but it reminds me that $\delta$ is determined by $\epsilon$) such that when $|x - x_0| < \delta_{\epsilon}$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)|$ "have no choice"/"are forced to" "must" be less than or equal to $\epsilon$.

So how do you find this $\delta_{\epsilon}$?  Well you start where you want to conclude and work backwards.

$|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$  (what does that say about $|x - x_0|$?)

$|3x + 7 - 3x_0 -7| = |3(x - x_0)| <\epsilon$

Therefore

$|x - x_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

So $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{3}$ is the value that will work.

And let's make sure it does:

"Prove f(x) is continuous at all $x_0$"

For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = \epsilon/3$

Thus if $|x - x_0| < \delta$ then

$|3x - 3x_0| = |3x + 7 - 3x_0 -7| = |f(x) - f(x_0)| < 3\cdot\delta = 3\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{3}= \epsilon$

Thus it is continuous.

Cool!  That was the correct value for delta.

Comment: You might consider \cdot for your multiplication.

Comment: a$\cdot$b.  I'll try to remember that.  MathJax is kind of a pain (until you consider the alternative).